# Styled Components Typescript Inference

Tags: typescript, styled-components

So I've been running into an issue where my theme type isn't being properly inferred into the styled components. Inference works fine when I use the `css` function but not when I use something like `styled.div`. Any ideas? Would love to not have to manually add a type for each type I reference props.theme

[image]

[image]

This is what my `styled.d.ts` file looks like
[image]